# iOS binding project - Error MSB6006: "zip" exited with code 255

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-binding

I have been trying to bind the [PayPalHereSDKv2 from this cocoa pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/PayPalHereSDKv2). I have, I think, bound the project and its dependencies but now when I go to build I am getting this error:

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/iOS/Xamarin.iOS.ObjCBinding.CSharp.targets(3,3): Error MSB6006: "zip" exited with code 255. (MSB6006) (PayPalHereSDKv2.PodBinding.iOS)

Not to sure where to go from here? has anyone ever seen this?

Comment: If you enable diagnostic level logging for MSBuild, do you get more details?

Comment: Never really got anything from the logging but it seemed to disappear?? after trying to add in different native references?? Not to sure what fixed it, native references were possibly not correct.